# TabView ( page style) does not scale to fit it's item swiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, tabview

I am using a tabView for a sliding header on a mobile app I have an object for the tabItem view, an object for the TabView and another object as the main view
the issue is the object that is written on the mainView doesn't have enough height to show the tabItems wide. here is the code that I wrote:

```swift
//This code is used to make a view for tabItem
struct FeaturedItemView: View {
    // MARK: - PROPERTIES
    var player: Player
    
    var body: some View {
        Image(player.image)
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .cornerRadius(12)
    }
}
```

```swift
//This Code is used for create a view for TabView object
struct FeaturesTabView: View {
    // MARK: - PROPERTIES

    // MARK: - BODY
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            ForEach(players) { player in
                FeaturedItemView(player: player)
                    .padding(.top, 10)
                    .padding(.horizontal, 15)
                    
            }//: FOREACH
        }//: TABVIEW
        .tabViewStyle(.page)
        .indexViewStyle(.page(backgroundDisplayMode: .always))
    }
}
```

```swift
//This is the mainView
struct ContentView: View {
  
  // MARK: - BODY
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 10) {
                NavigationBarView()
                    .padding(.horizontal, 15)
                    .padding(.bottom)
                    .padding(.top, UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.safeAreaInsets.top)
                    .background(Color.white)
                    .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.05), radius: 5, x: 0, y: 5)
                
                ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                    VStack(spacing: 0) {
                        // The issue is occurred here
                        // ******************
                        FeaturesTabView()
                            .padding(.vertical, 20)
                        //****************

                        FooterView()
                            .padding(.horizontal)
                    }//: VSTACK
                    
                }//: SCROLL
                
            }//: VSTACK
            .background(colorBackground.ignoresSafeArea(.all, edges: .all))
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea(.all, edges: .top)
    }
}
```

the view that shows is something like below:

[image]

but the view that is expected is the below:

[image]

Comment: Could you fix the issue by using TabView?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your `FeaturesTabView` is collapsing in the `ScrollView` without a `.frame`. In order to make it adaptable, put a `GeometryReader` on your view, and then set your `.frame()` to whatever portion of the screen you want it to take up. As an example, I gave it 1/3 of the height of the screen. Because of the `.scaledToFit()`, the image will expand it's width to stay proportional on the screen, so you do not need to set width on the frame.

```
struct ContentView: View {
  
  // MARK: - BODY
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ZStack {
                VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 10) {
                     NavigationBarView()
                         .padding(.horizontal, 15)
                         .padding(.bottom)
                         .padding(.top, UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.safeAreaInsets.top)
                         .background(Color.white)
                         .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.05), radius: 5, x: 0, y: 5)
                
                      ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                          VStack(spacing: 0) {
                            // Put a frame on your view to prevent it from collapsing in the ScrollView
                             FeaturesTabView()
                               .padding(.vertical, 20)
                               .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height / 3)

                            FooterView()
                               .padding(.horizontal)
                       }//: VSTACK
                    
                   }//: SCROLL
                
               }//: VSTACK
               .background(colorBackground.ignoresSafeArea(.all, edges: .all))
           }
           .ignoresSafeArea(.all, edges: .top)
        }//: GEOMETRYREADER
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer @Yrb, the problem is I cannot define the FeaturesTabView height size based upon the entire scroll view height because the scrollView height will be dynamic and It will be changed by adding Items. I must just set the FeaturesTabView size with the FeaturedItemView size when it's scaled to fit.

Comment: It's a `ScrollView`. Its whole reason for existence is to contain more information than will fit on the screen. If you want the `FeaturesTabView` to display at a certain size, you are going to have to give it that size. I made an example of 1/3, but you can set it however you want.